# Jasper Report won't load

Tags: jasper-reports

I have this code to basically divide tax from qty and subtract from price:

$F{unitPriceStd}.subtract($F{taxAmt}.divide($F{totalQty}))

But the jrxml won't load. removing this piece of code will load the .jrxml.  Any idea why?

All fields are BigDecimal.

Reason for error is taxAmt is 0.00 and causes error when dividing to totalQty.  Any idea how to fix this?

Answer (score 1):

There is a whole range of exceptions that this expression might throw and `taxAmt` being zero is actually none of them. This modified expression is `NullPointerException` and `ArithmeticException` safe, however, I cannot tell if this is what your business logic requires:

`($F{unitPriceStd} == null ? BigDecimal.ZERO : $F{unitPriceStd})
.subtract(
($F{taxAmt} == null ? BigDecimal.ZERO : $F{taxAmt})
.divide(
($F{totalQty} == null || $F{totalQty}.equals(BigDecimal.ZERO)) ? BigDecimal.ONE : $F{totalQty}
))`

Comment: Very nice answer, for OP business logic, maybe a printWhenExpression on $F{unitPriceStd} != null